# jQuery Error - missing : after property id

Tags: jquery, properties

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input#zip').autocomplete({
            var cityAndState = joinedValues.split("|")[1];
            dataType: "json",
            source: "../src/php/registration/getFanLoc.php",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, args) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var joinedValues = args.item.value;
                var id = joinedValues.split("|")[0];
                var cityAndState = joinedValues.split("|")[1];
                document.getElementById('actualZip').value = id;
                document.getElementById('zip').value = cityAndState;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

JavaScript Console in FF is throwing this error:

```
missing : after property id
[Break On This Error]   

var cityAndState= joinedValues.split("|")[1];
```

How do I fix this? I'm a bit confused and really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you:

```
var cityAndState = joinedValues.split("|")[1];
```

**cannot appear in an object literal.**

Comment: THanks for the response. Where should it be placed then?

Comment: Do you understand what it does?

Answer (score 0):

put this line before `$('input#zip').autocomplete`:

```
var cityAndState= joinedValues.split("|")[1];
```

so your code looks like this:

```
$(document).readh(function() {
    var cityAndState= joinedValues.split("|")[1];
    $('input#zip').autocomplete({
        // ...
    });
});
```

but I don't see any practical usage of `cityAndState` variable, so is it really required?

Comment: Its splitting the values from an array. This code did not fix it.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you use the `cityAndState` variable, the **source** of autocomplete is a remote url, and the **select** callback declares its own `cityAndState` variable, so why do you declare the `cityAndState` variable?